# total variation distance: $\max_{A \subseteq \mathcal{A}} \left| P(A)-Q(A) \right| = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{x \in \mathcal{A}} \left| P(x) - Q(x)\right|$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, reference-request, total-variation

Could you please suggest a **proof or a reference that shows a proof of the following equality (not "passing through the densities" as done in [Definition of the total variation distance: $ V(P,Q) = \frac{1}{2} \int |p-q|d\nu$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1481101/definition-of-the-total-variation-distance-vp-q-frac12-int-p-qd-n))**, where left-hand side and right-hand side are both used as definitions of the total variation distance between two probability measures, $P$ and $Q$?
\begin{equation}
\max_{A \subseteq \mathcal{A}} \left| P(A)-Q(A) \right| =
\frac{1}{2} \sum_{x \in \mathcal{A}} \left| P(x) - Q(x)\right|
\end{equation}

Comment: I think the proof is the same as [this one which you have already seen](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1481101/definition-of-the-total-variation-distance-vp-q-frac12-int-p-qd-n). Just replace the densities $p, q$ with the PMFs $P$, $Q$, and replace integrals with sums.

Comment: thanks angryavian! I have just found the proof by @am_rf24, from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3415641/total-variation-distance-l1-norm By chance,  do you know any reference to a textbook or a paper? :-)

Comment: I found another proof for my question (even though they use the supremum instead of the maximum): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3727561/total-variation-norm-of-probability-measures-related-to-l-1-norm

Comment: It is actually pretty straightforward if you are not intimidated by the look. Just realize the maximum of the left hand side is achieved only when $P(x)-Q(x)$ has the same sign for all $x\in A$, otherwise the opposite signed number cancel each other and we can achieve a larger number by cutting out the $x$ with the opposite sign. Also keep in mind the $P(x)-Q(x)$ summed over all sample space is $0$.

Comment: Thanks @Hans, very kind! :-)

Comment: In that proof, you should use densities.. I would like to see the proof without passing through densities (if possible) ...I think I would prefer this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3727561/total-variation-norm-of-probability-measures-related-to-l-1-norm

Answer (score 1):

I would read ``Markov Chains and Mixing Times'', second edition, by David A. Levin, Yuval Peres with contributions by Elizabeth L. Wilmer, Chapter 4. It is available online.

Comment: Thanks @Dimitrios D, Yes I have already read it :-)

Comment: @Ommo is the question about more interesting/creative/what-adjective(?) proofs then, or perhaps proofs that lead to insights for a particular problem?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Dimitros :-) I found very clear the proof & explanation provided by K. A. Buhr in "Total variation norm of probability measures related to 1
-norm?" (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3727561/total-variation-norm-of-probability-measures-related-to-l-1-norm). To reply to your question, i.e. "is the question about more interesting/creative/what-adjective(?) proofs ....", I do not think so :-)